# I get the following error "at most one record can be returned by this subquery"

Tags: ms-access

This code is meant to pull the status for the projects, 2 most recent dates and return all projects that are 3 last report and most recent report. I however keep getting the error that only one record can be returned by this sub query and the query takes forever to run. Please help.

```
SELECT RedProjectHistorical.[Project Name]
FROM (
    select 
        'Project Name',
    max('Report Date') as maxrd
    from RedProjectHistorical
    group by RedProjecthistorical.'Project Name'
) AS RedProjectHistorical 
WHERE 3 = (
    SELECT 
       t2.[Internal Project Status Value] 
    from RedProjectHistorical as t2
    where 
        t2.[Project Name] = RedProjectHistorical.[Project Name] 
        and t2.[Report Date] = RedProjectHistorical.maxrd
) 
and 3 = (
    select top 1 t2.[Internal Project Status Value] 
    from RedProjectHistorical t2 
    where 
        t2.[Project Name] = RedProjectHistorical.[Project Name] 
        and t2.[Report Date] <RedProjectHistorical.maxrd 
    order by t2.[Report Date] desc
); `
```

Comment: Yes and no. Yes in that the first subquery returns the most recent report date for all "Project Name". No in that the it also returns the most recent date for projects that did not have anything reported in the most recent reporting period. I.e. projects that were last reported on a year ago. I only want those that were reported on in the most recent date seen in the entire report.

Comment: My apologies. For the first subquery I omitted the following. It is actually `SELECT 'Project Name', max('Report Date') as maxrd
      from RedProjectHistorical
      group by RedProjectHistorical.'Project Name'`                                                       - See the change in the last `group by` clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try use exists condition like this:

```
exists(SELECT 1
  from RedProjectHistorical as t2
  where t2.[Project Name] = RedProjectHistorical.[Project Name] 
    and t2.[Report Date] = RedProjectHistorical.maxrd
    and t2.[Internal Project Status Value] = 3)
```